# use data / string php in html?

Tags: php

if i use this file php

```
<?php 
        $val= $_GET['id']; 
        echo $val     
 ?>
```

and i open this url : localhost/c.php?id=Servervalue1 => WebSitevalue2.com
i see that

```
Servervalue1 => WebSitevalue2.com
```

and i want to get this

```
   <ul><li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-src="WebSitevalue2.com">Servervalue1</a></li></li></ul>
```

How Can i get this ?

Comment: Read up on [explode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), see if that helps

Comment: @kerbholz Thank Youu